# How to create on LOOP

Tags: autoit

Hello i have dev one script but idon't know how to make for increment a system with one for loop and write in text file a loop.

```
for $i = 0 to 2
    $sSectionFight = "SORT" & ($i + 1) & "=NULL"
    IniWriteSection($filePathConfig & $choixDeLaConfig, "FIGHT",  $sSectionFight)

Next
```

With the code i have

```
SORT3=NULL
```

But i need

```
SORT1=NULL
SORT2=NULL
```

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$sSectionFight = "SORT" & ($i + 1) & "=NULL"
IniWriteSection($filePathConfig & $choixDeLaConfig, "FIGHT",  $sSectionFight)
```

with

```
IniWrite($filePathConfig & $choixDeLaConfig, "FIGHT", "SORT" & ($i + 1), "NULL")
```